# Running Google App Engine Locally in Debug Mode

Tags: google-app-engine

I have this error throw out when I tried to load my application in debug mode locally.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
  handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
  handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
  obj = _import_(path[0])
File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/ndvi-time-series/server.py", line 51, in <module>
  import firebase_admin
File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/ndvi-time-series/lib/firebase_admin/_init_.py", line 23, in <module>
  from firebase_admin import credentials
File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/ndvi-time-series/lib/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 20, in <module>
  import google.auth
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1149, in load_module
  raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named google.auth
```

I tried to trace the issue but I have no clue what went wrong.

Can anyone give me some enlightenment and assist me on how can I source the problem?

Thanks

**Add-on:**

After taking in the advise that Sami Islam has commented, I was repeatedly being prompted to authenticate earthengine, which I have done so before I started running 'dev_appserver.py app.yaml'

The error I got:

```
ERROR    2018-09-04 06:51:31,938 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud- 
sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, 
in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud- 
sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, 
in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud- 
sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in 
LoadObject
obj = _import_(path[0])
File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/ndvi-time-series/server.py", line 90, in 
<module>
ee.Initialize()
File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/ndvi-time-series/lib/ee/_init_.py", line 93, in 
Initialize
credentials = _GetPersistentCredentials()
File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/ndvi-time-series/lib/ee/_helpers.py", line 40, 
in 
_GetPersistentCredentials
raise EEException('Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account '
EEException: Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account by running

earthengine authenticate

in your command line, and then retry.
INFO     2018-09-04 06:51:31,961 module.py:880] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2018-09-04 06:51:32,458 instance.py:294] Instance PID: 31367
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the end of the error message that you are receiving you can see the following line ’ImportError: No module named google.auth’. It means that the path to the location of the module was not found. It is expecting the google.auth module and the firebase_admin module to be located in the default location of the google package. You can point the debugger to find the google package by providing the path directory in the appengine_config.py. This way the debugger will be able to find the location of the package and will not show the ImportError. In order to change the location on where to find the google package and point towards the directory please try adding the following command lines to the appengine_config.py file.

```
#appengine_config.py
import os
import google
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

lib_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/lib'

# Change where to find the google package (point to the lib/ directory)
google.__path__ = [os.path.join(lib_directory, 'google')] + google.__path__

# Add any libraries and install it in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add(lib_directory)
```

Comment: Looking at the response, It seems that the Google Earth Engine API is unable to process the authentication method inside your code, I would highly suggest following the best practice to setup the App Engine with Google Earth Engine to setup the local Python development environment through the following article [1]                     [1] https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/app_engine_intro#3-set-up-the-local-development-environment